# handle strongly types with enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have a doubt with `enums` if I defined a `enums` that inherited from short like this:

```
public enum ProyectoEstatus : short
{
    EstatusPorDefecto = 26,
    AprobadoUnidadNegocio = 6,
    CanceladoAreaComercial = 18
}
```

why am i unble to do this??

```
Nullable<short> aux = ProyectoEstatus.CanceladoAreaComercial as ProyectoEstatus;
```

If my type of my variable called aux is `Nullable`

Comment: The `as` operator must be used with reference types, while your `ProyectoEstatus` is an enum, i.e. value type. You don't need `as` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `enum` type itself is not nullable, so the `as` operator will not work on it.

Secondly, the `enum` type is not actually a `short`. It is a `short`-backed enum type, but it will need to be explicitly cast into a short before it can undergo the *implicit* cast from `short` to `Nullable<short>`:

```
    Nullable<short> aux = (short)ProyectoEstatus.CanceladoAreaComercial
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of your enum is `ProyectoEstatus` and not `short`. It will stored in a `short` but the types are different and you will have to explicitly cast it to `short`:

```
Nullable<short> aux = (short) ProyectoEstatus.CanceladoAreaComercial;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cast to short:

```
Nullable<short> aux = (short)(ProyectoEstatus.CanceladoAreaComercial as ProyectoEstatus);
```

Given you're casting to short anyway, you can probably lose the cast to ProyectoEstatus:

```
Nullable<short> aux = (short)(ProyectoEstatus.CanceladoAreaComercial);
```

Comment: "as ProyectoEstatus" is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Nullable<short> aux = (short)ProyectoEstatus.CanceladoAreaComercial;
```

Answer (score 1):

When I try that code I get:

> The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type
>   ('UserQuery.ProyectoEstatus' is a non-nullable value type)

This seems self explanatory. The enum is a value type and so using "as" with it is not allowed.

If I try it without the `as ProyectoEstatus` I get:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'UserQuery.ProyectoEstatus' to
>   'short?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Again this is self explanatory. We should use an explicit conversion.

If I do an explicit conversion as follows it works:

```
Nullable<short> aux = (short)ProyectoEstatus.CanceladoAreaComercial;
```

Also what situations are you expecting this to be null? If you are trying to convert an enum value to the nullable short then the enum value will never be null so it seems unnecessary to make aux nullable at a glance. Is your actual code more complicated than this example?

Comment: It's not that you're expecting it to be null, it's that you're expecting it to possibly be of another type, and not actually a "whatever class is used with the 'as' clause" since as will try to set it to null if the type doesn't match.

Comment: @Servy: ah yes, of course. Given that wasn't valid I'd thrown that out of my mind already, forgetting that this was probably the original intent.

Comment: Yeah, I just know a lot of people that built the habit of using the 'as' keyword rather than casting, and it can bite you when it comes to structs.